# Access value from controller in directive

Tags: angularjs

I'll put my code in and then I'll explain what I'm trying to accomplish.

My directive:

```
chat.directive('autoScroll', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            totalHeight: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var parent = element.parent('div.chat-text');
            $timeout(function() {
                scope.totalHeight += element.height();
            }, 0);
            parent.scrollTop(scope.totalHeight);
        }
    };
});
```

And where I'm calling the directive:

```
<div id={{$index}} class='chat-window' ng-class='{active: chat.selected == true}' ng-click='selectChat($index)' ng-repeat='chat in chatWindows track by $index' resize-chat draggable='true' ondragstart='dragStart(event)'>
    <span class='title'>{{chat.name}}<i class='fa fa-times pull-right click' ng-click='remove(chatWindows, $index)'></i></span>
    <div class='chat-text'>
        <div class='message' ng-repeat='message in chat.messages' auto-scroll totalHeight='chat.totalHeight'>
            <span class='name'>{{message.user}}</span>
            <span class='time'>{{message.time}}</span>
            <p>{{message.message}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The directive is getting called on the div.message.
The chatWindows object and an idea of what the object I'm trying to access looks like:

```
$scope.chatWindows = [];
$scope.chatWindows.push({name: name, selected: true, totalHeight: 0, messages:[]});
```

So, now what I'm trying to accomplish. As messages are added to the chatWindow object, I want to get the height of that message, add it to the total height of the chatWindow object, and then move the scrollbar to that position.

Currently what's happening is I'm getting an error "Expression 'undefined' used with directive 'autoScroll' is non-assignable!".

I'm brand new to angular, and currently trying to wrap my head around directives, but having a really hard time finding out how to solve this issue.

Comment: Try using `@` to bind to the isolated scope. You don't really need a two way binding do you?

Comment: I thought I did need the two-way binding, I'm trying to edit the value in my directive, the value doesn't get edited anywhere else though (except being created in the controller). But I made the change you suggested, I don't get the error anymore, but the value is still being reported as undefined, so I can't do anything with it anyways.

Comment: Use `{{chat.totalHeight}}` and see what happens.

Comment: Saw that in your edited post. I tried it, using both @ and =, didn't get the error that I was seeing, but still just got an undefined value.

Comment: Do a full inheritance of the scope (remove the scope property) and see if you can get it to work. The directive will have access to the parent scope. If you can't get that to work, you have an issue with your scope.

Comment: How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the scope property in your directive definition object you have created an isolated scope for the directive. Anything you want from the parent scope must be passed down through attributes in the html.

You probably want to use interpolation with `{{chat.totalHeight}}`

I can't see why the interpolated value is not getting into your isolated scope, but just in case the `ngRepeat` directive is giving you grief, try putting your directive inside the repeated element.

```
<div id={{$index}} class='chat-window' ng-class='{active: chat.selected == true}' ng-click='selectChat($index)' ng-repeat='chat in chatWindows track by $index' resize-chat draggable='true' ondragstart='dragStart(event)'>
<span class='title'>{{chat.name}}<i class='fa fa-times pull-right click' ng-click='remove(chatWindows, $index)'></i></span>
<div class='chat-text'>
    <div class='message' ng-repeat='message in chat.messages'>
      <div auto-scroll totalHeight='{{chat.totalHeight}}'
        <span class='name'>{{message.user}}</span>
        <span class='time'>{{message.time}}</span>
        <p>{{message.message}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### or to ditch the isolated scope (don't do both of these):

```
chat.directive('autoScroll', function($timeout) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var parent = element.parent('div.chat-text');
        $timeout(function() {
            scope.chat.totalHeight += element.height();
        }, 0);
        parent.scrollTop(scope.chat.totalHeight);
    }
};
});
```

To answer the question regarding when we would want to isolate the scope, you will often want your directives to be scope agnostic so you can use the same directive anywhere in the application regardless of its parent scope. This is, in fact, usually what you will want to do. For example this directive (without an isolated scope) can only be used when the parent scope has a `chat.totalHeight` property. Not very re-usable.

Comment: Okay, so that's what I've done. Is there a better way to access the data that I want, other then what I've done?

And if not, how would I go about passing the data through attributes in the HTML?

Comment: From what I can see, one 'better way' would be to just pass in the `chatWindow` object.

Comment: I made some changes to my code based on this info and the fact that I realized I'm iterating through every chatWindow in the div.chat-window. Now what's happening is I'm getting this error, Expression 'undefined' used with directive 'autoScroll' is non-assignable!.

Comment: That solved my issue, thank you so much for bearing with me and walking through this with me, I appreciate it. By the way, I went with the second option, seemed cleaner to me. Is there ever a reason to use the isolated scope then, if this is so much easier?

Answer (score 0):

There could be a potential of totalHeight not be defined to begin with - some asynchronous issues I have faced in the past. You can try to add a watcher to be sure it is being defined properly.

```
chat.directive('autoScroll', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            totalHeight: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var parent = element.parent('div.chat-text');
            scope.$watch('totalHeight', function() {
               console.log(scope.totalHeight); //Not necessary but interesting to see what is going on
               if(!!scope.totalHeight) {              
                 scope.totalHeight += element.height();
                 parent.scrollTop(scope.totalHeight);
               }
        }
    };
});
```

Maybe this solves your problem maybe not, but I know I have come across similar issues in the past - I am not completely happy with the way this code works, feel a bit hacky, but unless someone else know a way to get around this issue of scope.$watch this stands for me...

Comment: I still get the same error. The page the error takes me to seems to want to tell me that I'm not defining the variable properly. But as far as I can tell, I am.

Comment: when u look in the console for the output what are you seeing?

Comment: what is defining chat.totalHeight? Maybe adding of this code would help to debug...

Comment: I've added what I see in the console, specifically the error I mention at the bottom of my post. Also chat is defined in my ng-repeat on div.chat-window (code is already there), totalHeight I show as being defined when I push an object onto the chatWindow object (near the bottom of my code).

Comment: I added a console.log in the watcher. You can see if the value is being defined or not as this would be very helpful to know where your problem is. Also there should be a controller that is in charge of the rest of your code otherwise where do you get the scoped vars from. So when I ask where is chat.totalHeight being deinfed I mean in the controller not the HTML.

Comment: Yea, I put in the console.log, and then I stated I am still getting the exact same error I have at the bottom of my question. Also, I have my controller code near the bottom that relates to the creation of the chatWindow object and pushing an object into it. I know the object is being created as I have access to chat.name and chat.messages in the HTML. I can also output chat.totalHeight in the HTML, I just can't seem to pass it.

Comment: ... these are different issues, when u r passing somethign to an isolate scope and u are using it to do 'things' you can have asynchronous issues... so that is why i asked to output the value from the watcher in console to see what it outputs - it - undefined or a number.